# How to make good visualization of time series data using tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-desktop

The time series data looks like this:

| Month | Count1 | Count2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 100 |
| 2 | 40 | 200 |
| 3 | 100 | 17 |
| 4 | 21 | 12 |

I have tried to use area charts or basic line/bar charts to visualize the two counts based on the Month.

Are there any fancy way to visualize it? How about radial map?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, more a "what can I do with tableau" software question. You might want to try the [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange sites instead.

Comment: Line, bar and sometimes area charts are go-to charts for time series for good reasons. Not always sexy, but clear and useful. More specialized variations on those chart types are helpful sometimes. You might want to read about horizon charts, connected scatter plots and Zvinca plots for example. I've only found radial charts useful when studying periodic behavior - say viewing data that follows an hourly or seasonal pattern that sort-of repeats each day or year. The usual advice is to first clearly show the data before going too far into visual design.